# how to convert a string into a fake array in bash script?

Tags: json, bash, shell, scripting

I know there are several posts on converting a string to an array but I have some specific requirements and my data is not consistent.

Here is what I am trying to do -

I am trying to pull server details from filebeat using bash script and pushing the data to kafka. Each server data contains network, cpu, services, memory, users etc which is a ton of data. Some of my servers have one IP address and some multiple IP addresses. I am struggling to convert those single IP address (a string) to a fake array. I tried with sed but it's altering the real array IP data.

String :

```
{
"network_ip_gateway": "1.2.3.4",

"network_ip_v4_address": "1.2.3.4",
}
```

An array:

```
{
   “network_ip_v4_address”: “1.2.3.4",
   “mac_address”: “A0:B1:C3:D4",
   “network_ip_v4_address”: [
       “1.2.3.4",
       “1.2.3.4”
   ],
   “network_gateway_address”: [
       “1.2.3.4”,
       “1.2.3.4"
   ]
}
```

Here is what tried

```
cat test.json |grep network_ip |sed 's/\"network_ip_v4_address": "/"network_ip_v4_address": ["/g'|sed 's/\"network_ip_gateway": "/"network_ip_gateway": ["/g' | sed 's/\,/],/g'
```

Comment: The question is not crystal clear ... 

Comment: You'd be better off using `jq` to parse json, rather than `sed` and `grep`.

Comment: What is a "fake array"?

Comment: `sed 's/\("network_ip_\(v4_address\|gateway\)":\) *\("[^"]*"\)/\1 [\n      \3\n   ]/'`